# Script for replacing the file name if it exists?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

I'm trying to make a script that changes the name of the file if the file already exists to something like file1.txt, but I keep getting the same error: Syntax error: unexpected end of file So far I have done this:

```
#! /bin/bash
FILE=/home/skrips/file.sh
ls -l /home/skrips/*/
ls /home/skrips/*/ > $(date '+%d:%m:Y%').file.txt
if [ -f " $FILE" ]; then
mv -i $(date '+%d:%m:Y%').file.txt file.txt $(date '+%d:%m:Y%').file+1
fi
```

Comment: Run your script through [ShellCheck – shell script analysis tool](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and fix the errors.

Comment: @DavidPostill Wow thanks that's a great tool! Fixed the error, but the script was supposed to create the file called ( current date).file.txt, but instead it created the file called (current date).txt+1 Can u help fix this issue?

Comment: No idea about that. I'm no bash expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the script working with this script:

```
#! /bin/bash
ls -l /home
date=$(date +%F)
end_a="-file"
end_b=".txt"
number=1
counter=0
continue=$(echo $(($number + $counter)))
file=${date}${end_a}${continue}${end_b}
while [ -f $file ]; do
let counter=counter+1 continue=$(echo $(($number + $counter)))
file=${date}${end_a}${continue}${end_b}
done
Is -l /home > $file
```

Answer (score 1):

(not an answer, but a formatted comment)

```sh
if [ -f " $FILE" ]; then
# .......^
```

What's that space doing there?

I strongly recommend you use date format `%Y-%m-%d`. Not only is that the ISO standard format, it also sorts the same chronologically and lexically -- `ls` will show them in the right order.